# How to filter events in Ether js

Tags: ethers.js

```
  async getLogs() {
    const logs = await this.provider.getLogs({
      fromBlock: 12794325,
      toBlock: 'latest',
      address: this.Dao.address,
      topics: , //filter
    });
    console.log(logs);
  }
```

how to filter logs to get only events called 'newProposal'

```
Event newProposal (address,  uint256 ,  string )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const filter = [utils.id('newProposal(address,uint256,string)')];
    this.logs = await this.provider.getLogs({
      fromBlock: 12794325,
      toBlock: 'latest',
      address: this.Dao.address,
      topics: filter,
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const abi = ["Event newProposal (address,  uint256 ,  string )"]

const contract = new Contract(cttAddress, abi, provider)

const filter = contract.filters.newProposal(null, null, null)
```

Insteed of null use the params that you want to use. If for example you were looking for more then one address put all of them inside `[]`

You can check more here:
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/concepts/events/